# Can't Create Session Inside image.php in Codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, session

I want to create a simple captcha verification form and it looks like this:

```
  <form>
  <br/>Captcha :<img class="captcha" src="<?php echo base_url('application/views/captcha/image.php')?>">    
  <br/><br/><input type="username" required class="i" name="captcha" id="i7" size="25"/> 
  <br><br><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="submit" value="Register"/>
  </form>
```

Here's the image.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
header("Content-Type: image/png");
$text = rand(1000,100000);
$_SESSION['code'] = $text;
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg("bg.jpg");
$font = "arial.ttf";
$R = rand(0,100);
$G = rand(0,100);
$B = rand(0,100);
$TxtColor = imagecolorallocate($img,$R,$G,$B);
imagettftext($img,rand(40,45),rand(0,1),rand(10,70),rand(38,50),$TxtColor,$font$text);    
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

It works fine outside Codeigniter.  In Codeigniter, whenever I try to retrieve the value of `$text` from the session I get an error message as "Undefined index: code".  If I use Codeigniter's `userdata()` method as following:

```
 $this->session->set_userdata($text);
```

The captcha image doesn't even show.

Comment: I don't think that's the right way to load the image.php, you must create a controller for the image

Answer (score 2):

In Codignitor you need to load session library before set the session:

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Than you can set session by using array:

```
$array["code"] = $text;
$this->session->set_userdata($array);
```

When you need to print:

```
$this->session->userdata("code");
```

[CI SESSION USER GUIDE](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: session library is already loaded in autoload.php file. if i further load it in image.php the captcha image goes away!

Comment: Than y u need `session_start();` in image.Php @aw-wasi